# SQL display and fetch GROUP BY categories

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a list of authors and I would like to display it by book genre, like this:

```
Horror
    Stephen King
    Author 2
    Author 3
    ...

Comedy
    Author 4
    Author 5
    ...
```

In my database I have an author table:

**t_author**

```
aut_name      |  aut_genre
Stephen King  |  1
...
...
Author 4      |  2
```

And a genre table :

**t_genre**

```
genre_id      | genre_name
1             | Horror
2             | Comedy
...
...
```

I've tried to use a GROUP BY but I can't find how to display the names of the category and organize my list:

```
SELECT t_author.aut_name, t_author.aut_genre
FROM t_author 
LEFT JOIN t_genre ON t_author.aut_genre = t_genre.genre_id
GROUP BY t_genre.aut_genre
```

So, using MySQL and PDO, **is there a way to select and fetch all the authors and display it by categories?**

No need to say that I'm not looking for a code but just a clue because I don't even see how to describe it. I mean, is GROUP BY the right statement to use?

**EDIT 1 :**

Apparently, I was looking for something like this :

```
SELECT t_author.aut_name, t_author.aut_slug, t_genre.genre_name
FROM t_author
LEFT JOIN t_genre ON t_author.genre_id = t_genre.genre_id
```

But it displays:

```
Horror
   Stephen King
Horror
   Author 2
Comedy
   Author 4
Horror
   Author 3
```

I perfectly understand why but I can't find how to display it like below:

```
Horror
    Stephen King
    Author 2
    Author 3
    ...

Comedy
    Author 4
    Author 5
    ...
```

**Answer**

HtmHell provided me a good way to do this with a 2D array. For my 3D array, I edited his code like this:

```
foreach($result as $author=> $slug) {
        $authorsByGenre[$slug['genre_name']][] = array($slug['aut_name'] => $slug['aut_slug']); 
    }
    return $authorsByGenre;
```

Comment: Yes of there is, but thats not how SO works. You try something, it does not work as you hoped, you ask us for help, we offer possible solutions. **SO is not a free coding site**

Comment: This has nothing to do with PDO, or MySQL technically. This comes down to learning SQL...

Comment: Sorry but at first, I tried to make a query per category but I was sure this was not the best choice since I had a growing list of categories. Then, I'm pretty sure this has to do with the GROUP BY statement but I can't see how to use it with multiple categories...

Comment: Your table t_genre does not have a column named aut_genre try instead of `t_author.aut_genre = t_genre.aut_genre` this `t_author.aut_genre = t_genre.genre_name`

Comment: Thank you for your answers ; I've understood what was the problem and edited my question.

Comment: Search for `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$authorsByGenre = [];

$results = $db->query("
    SELECT      t_author.aut_name, t_genre.genre_name
    FROM        t_genre
    JOIN        t_author
    ON          t_author.aut_genre = t_genre.genre_id
")->fetchAll();

foreach ($results as $data) {
    $authorsByGenre[$data['genre_name']][] = $data['aut_name'];
}

print_r($authorsByGenre);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. I edited your code to get a 3D (see my edited question).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t_author.aut_name) as authors, t_genre.genre_name as genre FROM t_author 
LEFT JOIN t_genre ON t_author.aut_genre = t_genre.genre_id
 GROUP BY t_author.aut_genre
```

This will output authors as author1,author2,author3 in column 1 and genre column with genre_name so you can split or explode authors or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Like it was suggested in the comments, [PDO::FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group) is the answer to your question. Dunno why you ignored it

```
$sql = "SELECT genre_name, aut_name, aut_slug 
        FROM t_author a LEFT JOIN t_genre g ON a.genre_id = g.genre_id";
$authorsByGenre = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
print_r($authorsByGenre);
```